# Preserving sreg in AVR interrupts

Tags: assembly, arduino, avr, atmel

What is the mechanism used to preserve the status register, sreg, in an AVR microcontroller?  `RETI` implies that these bits are not on the stack.  Is one of the general purpose registers also the sreg or something like that?

Comment: The Status Register is not a general purpose register. It resides in the I/O register file and can be accessed using `in` and `out` instructions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is explained in every AVR datasheet. For example on page 8 of the [ATtiny2313 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc2543.pdf) it says:

> The Status Register is not automatically stored when entering an interrupt routine and restored when returning from an interrupt. This must be handled by software.

You can achieve this by storing it in a temporary register:

```
 interrupt:
     in r16, SREG   ; save SREG

     ...

     out SREG, r16  ; restore SREG
     reti
```

Also note that if you're accessing registers that are not exclusively used in this interrupt routine, you need to save those, too. Furthermore you can push the value of SREG to the stack if you're low on registers:

```
 interrupt:
     push r16      ; save global registers on stack
     push r17
     push r18
     in r16, SREG  ; save SREG
     push r16      ; do this if you want to use r16 in your interrupt routine

     ...

     pop r16       ; do this if you pushed SREG above
     out SREG, r16 ; restore SREG
     pop r18       ; restore global registers
     pop r17
     pop r16
     reti
```

For more information look [here](http://www.avr-asm-tutorial.net/avr_en/beginner/JUMP.html#Ints).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively

```
PUSH Rn
LDS Rn, SREG
PUSH Rn
```

and

```
POP Rn
STS SREG, Rn
POP Rn
```

seems to be valid.

Comment: Close!  But this doesn't save SREG -- I *think* it saves the EECR register.  But at least I have verified that the above won't save/restore SREG.

Comment: ...The IN and OUT mnemonics operate on data registers 0 to 0x3F.  When you access the same locations with LDS or STS, you need to add 0x20 to it.  In this case, you would use `LDS Rn, SREG + 0x20` and `STS SREG + 0x20, Rn`

I'm surprised nobody caught that for almost five years!